# How can I use @using in partial view?

Tags: c#, javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a grid filled with notes and I want to be able to add a new note. This works using two different views, but that makes the CreateNote view open a new window. I want this to open in the same window. So instead of a View I use a PartialView. This works, but the "@using (UI.koform(Model, null))" is seen as html so the knockoutjs doesn't work. How can I make this work in a partial view?

Code:

The view:

```
[...]
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        $('#load-partial').click(function() {
            $('#partial').load('@Url.Action("CreateNote", "Entity", new {modelEntity = @Model.meta.entity})');
        });
    })();   
</script>

<div id="partial"></div>
<button type="button" id="load-partial">Create Note</button>
```

The action:

```
public ActionResult CreateNote(
        [ModelBinder(typeof(Models.JsonModelBinder))]
        NoteModel Model, string cmd, string modelEntity)
    {  
        [...]
        return PartialView("CreateNotePartial",Model);

        }
```

The Partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="test.Web.Framework.Core.ViewUserControl<test.Web.Framework.Areas.Administration.Models.NoteModel>" %>
@using (UI.koform(Model, null))
{
<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all highlight" data-bind="visible: meta.message">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"></span><strong data-bind="text: meta.message">
    </strong>
</div>

Subject:
<input type="text" data-bind="value:subject" />
<span data-bind="text: subject"></span>
<br />
Text:
<input type="text" data-bind="value:text" />
<br />

<a href="#" data-bind="click:function(){setvalues() }">set values</a>


<div class="dialogButtons">
    <button onclick="$('#@Model.meta.modelname').koform('submit');">
        Save</button>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `<html>` tags mixed in several places in your partial view?

Comment: I still had that in because I copied this from a View where it didn't work without the <html> tags to the PartialView, removed it now. Still have the same problem.

Comment: Wait, can you mix the webforms <% %> syntax with razor's @?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing View engines.  Your control definition is using ASPX View engine syntax (`<%@ %>`) while your `using` statement is using Razor.  My guess is if you changed the code to this it would work:

```
<% using (UI.koform(Model, null))
{ %>

<%--  HTML  --%>

<% } %>
```